# How to change ortograph correction in WhatsApp on Android 13

Tags: keyboard, oneplus

I have a OnePlus phone. When I type particular words that I use a lot like: "pos", it will change it to uppercase "POS".

I tried to add "pos" to the dictionary, but it is still changing it. I don't want to turn the correction off, because it is very helpful, I just want to correct some errors it does.

How should I do it?